# Hide/show add-in depending on the subject(or something else) of the message(Office 365 Outlook add-in)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I want to show add-in only for certain messages in office365 in outlook. For example, I received a message with the subject "invoice" and the add-in should be visible, but if the subject does not contain this word "invoice" in the subject, then the add-in shouldn't be visible. Is it possible?

[My custom add-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vHc1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can control when your add-in is enabled based on a number of factors (it includes an address, a phone number, has a specific subject, etc.). You can even use RegEx patterns for matching.

See [Contextual Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins) for instructions.

Comment: This is correct, but the rules only apply to Contextual Add-ins which highlight in the body. So there is no way to get just a Subject Rule to highlight. There is also no way to apply rules to the icons that show up. (In the Ribbon in Desktop Outlook, and in your screenshot in OWA). Those will show up on all applicable places of that extension point. (MailRead, MailCompose, Appointment Organizer, or Appointment Attendee)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what interests me. It works only with contextual add-ins.
Marc, thank you very much!